# Making a 3D globe

Tags: javascript, css, html

I tried to make a 3D globe like in [**this page**](https://joshcarllewis.com/static/articles/html5-3d-canvas-tutorial/demo.html), but failed. I have zero knowledge in *HTML5* and *CSS/CSS3*, I just pasted the code provided into the [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kdeo4zd6/7), but I got nothing.

```
window.requestAnimFrame = (function(callback){
return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
function(callback){
window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
};
})();

function animate(lastTime, angularSpeed, three){
// update this frame
var time = new Date().getTime();
var timeDiff = time - lastTime;
var angleChange = angularSpeed * timeDiff * 2 * Math.PI / 1000;
three.earth.rotation.y += angleChange;
lastTime = time;

// render this frame
three.renderer.render(three.scene, three.camera);

// next frame
requestAnimFrame(function(){
animate(lastTime, angularSpeed, three);
});
}

window.onload = function(){
var angularSpeed = 0.005;
var lastTime = 0;

// load renderer
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

// set a camera
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth /         window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);
camera.position.z = 700;

// create a scene
var scene = new THREE.Scene();

// add a texture to a material
var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("https://joshcarllewis.com/static/articles/html5-3d-canvas-tutorial/earth.jpg")
});

// create an earth object
var earth = new THREE.Mesh(new THREE.SphereGeometry(200, 50, 50), material);
earth.overdraw = true;
scene.add(earth);

// add a directional light source
var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff);
directionalLight.position.set(2, 1, 2).normalize();
scene.add(directionalLight);

// keep everything together to make passing it around easier
var three = {
renderer: renderer,
camera: camera,
scene: scene,
earth: earth
};

// Preload textures before begining animation
var textureImg = new Image();
textureImg.onload = function(){
animate(lastTime, angularSpeed, three, this);
};
textureImg.src = "https://joshcarllewis.com/static/articles/html5-3d-canvas-tutorial/earth.jpg";
};
```

Can anybody see what's wrong with my code?
Thanks.

Comment: Errors? Console output? What does I got nothing mean? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: what's wrong with your code is that it isn't your code.

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a substitute for a debugger.  "Here's all the code, it doesn't work, tell me what's wrong" isn't a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your fiddle is set to run onload, and you are setting `window.onload` so the code is never running because the onload has already ocurred.

[You should debug it on your own](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/setup/workspace/setup-devtools) before asking a question. [I've updated the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/kdeo4zd6/9/) so that the WebGL code is actually running.

However, the code is having Cross Domain issues accessing earth.jpg. That is a separate question that you can create a new post for (after you do your own debugging). I would start with trying to run the code on your local server, and downloading the image locally.

> THREE.WebGLRenderer: Texture is not power of two. Texture.minFilter
>   should be set to THREE.NearestFilter or THREE.LinearFilter. https://joshcarllewis.com/static/articles/html5-3d-canvas-tutorial/earth.jpg)
>
> DOMException: Failed to execute 'texImage2D' on
>   'WebGLRenderingContext': The cross-origin image at
>   https://joshcarllewis.com/static/articles/html5-3d-canvas-tutorial/earth.jpg
>   may not be loaded.(…)texImage2D @ three.js:25518uploadTexture @